# Xcode 14 - autocomplete not working for IF ELSE condition { if else }

Tags: xcode, xcode14

I have updated Xcode 14 and Ventura, but do not see autocomplete popup to appear when I try to type `if else` condition.

How can i get autocomplete for `if else` statement. I can use Snippets Library but i want the old style.

Answer (score 1):

Type three letters atleast to get if else autocomplete work

`ife`

then

autocomplete popup will appear

otherwise press control(^) + space to manually show popup